# context free grammar with certain inequalities

Tags: context-free-grammar, inequalities

**What could be the correct Context free grammar for the Language L= {a^i b^j a^k | j< i + k} ?**

I want to know about the correctness of following CFG for this-

```
S-> aaSbA | A | ^
A-> bAa | a
```

Are there any standard rules for getting strings satisfying **j < i + k**?

*Please help*

Comment: Your grammar does not allow `i` to be 1 so cannot be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is by breaking it down into simpler languages.  Start with the simple repeating languages:

*L*<sub>a</sub> = { a<sup>i</sup> } -> ε | *L*<sub>a</sub>a
  *L*<sub>ab</sub> = { a<sup>i</sup>b<sup>i</sup> } -> ε | a*L*<sub>ab</sub>b

Now you use those to build up your language.  The core of your language is *L*<sub>ab</sub>*L*<sub>ba</sub>.  That gives you the same pattern, but with j = i + k.  So to get <, you need to add at least one a either before or after.  So you end up with

S -> a*L*<sub>a</sub>*L*<sub>ab</sub>*L*<sub>ba</sub>*L*<sub>a</sub> | *L*<sub>a</sub>*L*<sub>ab</sub>*L*<sub>ba</sub>*L*<sub>a</sub>a

Now this grammar is ambiguous, so if you care about that sort of thing, you can refactor it to remove (or at least reduce) ambiguities, but that is another question.

Comment: Then is this the corresponding unambiguous CFG G:  S -> aA | Aa  A -> BCDB  B-> aB | ^  C -> aCb | ^  D -> bDa | ^

Comment: @RajChauhan: That's the same CFG -- its ambiguous, but correct for the language.

Comment: There are, unfortunately, no standard rules for reducing or eliminating ambiguity in a grammar -- ambiguity itself is undecidable, so its a hard problem.  One trick that sometimes works is trying to convert the grammar to LR(1) or LR(k) -- if that works then the grammar is deterministic and unambiguous.  But it doesn't always work.